Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder
I got an error 14:44:53,646 "ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Lab3/main.xhtml: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: /main.xhtml @66,75 <f:validateDoubleRange> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@78a16d7a"
this is my xhtml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="resources/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="head">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main_styles.css"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="plot.js"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:panelGroup id="plot_script">
            <h:outputScript>
                setTimeout(() => {
                renderPlot(
                JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(#{resultsBean.parseResultsToJson()})),
                #{resultsBean.current.r}
                )
                }, 0);
            </h:outputScript>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <div class="plot">
            <svg height="300" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <!-- Plot SVG elements -->
                <polygon class="plot_part" points="250,150 150,150 150,100"/>
                <rect class="plot_part" x="50" y="150" height="100" width="100"/>
                <path class="plot_part" d="M150 200 A50 50 100 0 0 200 150 L150 150 Z"/>
                <svg id="dots" height="300" width="300"/>
                <line stroke="black" x1="0" x2="300" y1="150" y2="150"/>
                <line stroke="black" x1="150" x2="150" y1="0" y2="300"/>
                <!-- Axis markers and text -->
                <polygon fill="black" points="150,0 144,15 155,15"/>
                <polygon fill="black" points="300,150 285,156 285,144"/>
                <!-- Labels for R and ½R -->
                <text fill="black" x="190" y="140">½R</text>
                <text fill="black" x="245" y="140">R</text>
                <text fill="black" x="40" y="140">-R</text>
                <text fill="black" x="85" y="140">-½R</text>
                <!-- Axis labels -->
                <text fill="black" x="160" y="10">Y</text>
                <text fill="black" x="290" y="140">X</text>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="fields">
            <h:form id="main_form">
                <div class="input">
                    <p>Выберите значение X</p>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]}" var="i">
                        <h:commandButton value="#{i}" action="#{resultsBean.current.setX(i)}" type="button">
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="plot_script main_table"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <p>Введите значение Y</p>
                    <h:inputText id="y" required="true" maxlength="6" value="#{resultsBean.current.y}">
                        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="-3" maximum="5"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message class="message" for="y" id="y_msg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <p>Выберите значение R</p>
                    <p:spinner id="spinner" value="#{resultsBean.current.r}" min="0.5" max="4" stepFactor="0.5">
                        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.5" maximum="4"/>
                        <p:ajax update="plot_script"/>
                    </p:spinner>
                    <h:message class="message" for="spinner" id="r_msg"/>
                </div>
                <h:commandButton id="submit_button" value="Отправить" action="#{resultsBean.addResult}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="y_msg r_msg main_table plot_script"/>
                </h:commandButton>
                <p:remoteCommand name="addResultFromPlot" update="y_msg r_msg main_table plot_script"
                                 action="#{resultsBean.addResultFromPlot}"/>
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <div class="result_table">
            <h:dataTable id="main_table" value="#{resultsBean.results}" var="result">
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Номер</f:facet>#{result.id}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Значение X</f:facet>#{result.x}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Значение Y</f:facet>#{result.y}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Значение R</f:facet>#{result.r}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Попадание</f:facet>#{result.successString}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Время нажатия</f:facet>#{result.formattedTime}</h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </div>
        <div class="switch_page_button">
            <h:button value="Перейти на страницу с часами" outcome="index"/>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>


So the main question i have is why do i get this error only when building using Ant? Maven build that I deploy works perfectly fine!
I have tried to replace <p:spinner with the <h:inputText just for debug and it fixes the error, but it's not the functionality that i want from my code

<p:spinner> requires primefaces.jar in /WEB-INF/lib. So, logically speaking, the only reason could be that your Ant script forgot to put it there.
